# How to replace text between certain characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Im trying to do a code coloring program where certain keywords are replaced with colorized text. Until now im able to succeed at replacing certain keywords but im not able to replace the words between the quotes. for example i would like to replace.

```
var message='"im some text"';
```

with

```
var message='<span style="color:yellow">im some text</span>';
```

Any help would be appreciated..:-D

Comment: This might give you an idea of what im trying to do.it is yet to do the replacing between the quotes though http://codepen.io/megatroncoder/pen/KzYGwY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace text between quotes in a string then use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with captured group regex and do something like this

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, '<span style="color:yellow">$1</span>');
```

```html
<div id="div">abc "asasa" abc</div>
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/nB6bC5/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds : glad to help you :)